# App. frozen after ListView is bound to data

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding

In my app., I have a ListView that is bound to a List of 'XMLFileModel', see code below.
When I populate this List with 340 items, it is OK I see no delay.
When I populate this List with 5640 items, the app. is frozen about 15 seconds.
When I populate this List with 12080 items, the app. is frozen about 50 seconds.
So I have 2 questions:
1) are these delays common delays you also face ?
2) I put the code in a BackgroundWorker but the application still freeze. Why ?

I can live with the delay, I have a progress bar to show user the processing but the problem is that the progress bar is filled to 100% and then hidden very quickly (less than 1 second) and then the app. is frozen with the ListView empty.
So it seems the delay is coming from the data binding processing.

Here is the code for the command that initiate the data loading:

```
private void OnSelectRootFolderCommand()
{
    var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    dialog.Description = "Select the XML files folder";
    var dialogResult = dialog.ShowDialog();
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        RootFolder = dialog.SelectedPath;
        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(RootFolder, "*.xml",
            IsSubfolders ? SearchOption.AllDirectories : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
            .Where(f => Path.GetExtension(f) == ".xml");
        ProgressBarVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        progressBarWorker.RunWorkerAsync(files);
    }
}
```

Here is the code for 'XMLFileModel':

```
public class XMLFileModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastWriteTime { get; set; }

    private string status;
    public string Status
    {
        get { return status; }
        set
        {
            if (status != value)
            {
                status = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (isSelected != value)
            {
                isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the method ran by BackgroundWorker RunWorkerAsync that binds the data:

```
private void ProgressBarWorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var filesList = new List<XMLFileModel>();

    try
    {
        var xmlFiles = e.Argument as IEnumerable<string>;
        if (xmlFiles != null && xmlFiles.Any())
        {
            var xmlFilesList = xmlFiles.ToArray();
            var filesCount = xmlFilesList.Count();
            int percentageDone = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < filesCount; i++)
            {
                var xmlFile = xmlFilesList[i];

                var fileModel = new XMLFileModel
                {
                    Name = xmlFile,
                    Status = ParseResultEnum.NotProcessed.ToString(),
                    LastWriteTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(xmlFile),
                    IsSelected = true
                };
                filesList.Add(fileModel);
                percentageDone = (int)(((i + 1.0d) / (double)filesCount) * 100.0d);
                progressBarWorker.ReportProgress(percentageDone);
            }
        }
        XMLFiles = filesList;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Services.Instance.Logger.Error(ex);
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            messageBoxService.ShowError(ex.Message));
    }
}
```

The delay starts when the above method 'ProgressBarWorkerDoWork' is completely executed.

Here is the XAML code for the view:

```
<Border DockPanel.Dock="Top" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="1">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ListView Margin="2" ItemsSource="{Binding XMLFiles, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
              dragdrop:DragDropHelper.IsDragSource="True" dragdrop:DragDropHelper.IsDropTarget="True">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="Error">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="Processed">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LimeGreen" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="Invalid">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="Ignored">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="700" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="DateTime" Width="144" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastWriteTime}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="88" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

Comment: Here are some additional information.

Comment: Here is some additional information.  As I wrote before, once the bound property is set, the UI freeze.  I set a breakpoint in the XMLFileModel Status setter property and WPF is calling it. Not a surprise but I don't understand why the UI is frozen.  Here is the call stack in case it could help:

Comment: Sorry call stack is too long, please let me know how to provide it if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that it's your call to `EnumerateFiles` that's blocking. You are making that call on the UI thread.

You are doing the correct thing in doing the bulk of your processing in a background thread, but I'd move the `EnumerateFiles` into the background worker too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for the long delay, I was abroad.   I moved the EnumerateFiles in the background worker but it didn't help.   I even tried using GetFiles but it didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.
This is the ScrollViewer that is nesting the ListView.
I didn't pay attention, it was not needed and I guess it is giving infinite vertical length and so breaking the virtualization that should be active by default for a ListView.
So, by just removing the ScrollViewer, the binding is done very quickly.